# error - NullpointException in an android app with DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, drawerlayout

I was trying to create a simple material design interface in android studio. I am getting error at particular line where I am opening drawer. As soon as I click home icon in actionbar (toolbar), the app crashes.

Here is the code I tried.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), "I'm a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Snackbar Action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I have tried to change the action of FAB and Home Icon, that is working !! But in normal drawer open with home icon, I get following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(int)' on a null object reference
        at jani.jigar.designdemo.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:67)
```

I have seen same cases, but they didn't initialized object. I did in the beginning. I can't find the error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: put DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout; on top of onCreate(); and cancel the same code inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're aliasing your activity's instance variable `mDrawerLayout` in the `onCreate` method with a local variable. And since scoping in Java goes from the inside out, you're never setting the reference of `mDrawerLayout` outside of the method. So all you need to in order to fix your issue is to remove `DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;` from `onCreate`.

Comment: I copied it to make it global but forgot to remove local. Thank you for spontaneous help.